# Generic function with generic container return types using generic evaluators

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to create a function which returns a generic container type which takes as input two other generic container types with generic evaluator(s) / delegates.

I want to avoid cluttering with more class names if it is possible but I'll do it if it's required...

Do I have to create another (redundant) generic class just to do this?

Note: ***I have to use Visual Studio 2013***.

Code example:

```
delegate bool MyEval1<T>(T a);
delegate bool MtEval2<T>(T a, T b);

// This does not compile...
List<T> SomeNiceFunction<T>(List<T> l1, List<T> l2, MyEval1<T> e1, MyEval2<T> e2) {
    List<T> result = new List<T>();
    foreach(var elem in l1) {
        var match = l2.FirstOrDefault(o => e1(o) && e2(o, elem));
        if (match != null)
            result.Add(match);
    }
    //... (some more code goes here)
    return result;
}
```

Thanks in advance :-)

**Edit**
After some help below I can summarize it as follows:

```
public static class Mumbo
{
    static List<T> Jumbo<T>(List<T> l1, List<T> l2, MyEval1<T> e1, MyEval2<T> e2) {
        List<T> result = new List<T>();
        // code goes here
        return result;
    }
}
```

It works now... Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegates are types not functions. You need to create a class for `SomeNiceFunction` but it doesn't need to be generic, just the method itself:

```
public static class Container {
    public static List<T> SomeNiceFunction<T>(List<T> l1, List<T> l2, MyEval1<T> e1, MyEval2<T> e2) {
    List<T> result = new List<T>();
    foreach(var elem in l1) {
        var match = l2.FirstOrDefault(o => e1(o) && e2(o, elem));
        if (match != null)
            result.Add(match);
    }
    //... (some more code goes here)
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: so I take it I have to clutter with a class name?

Comment: @DecafSux - You can't write top-level functions in C# no, all methods must go inside a class.

Comment: Ok. In my case I will have to create a static generic class with different template parameter types... Can I do this without providing a lot of dummy types? I really just want to use one or two types for the methods I intend to use.

Comment: @DecafSux - The containing class doesn't need to be generic, the method is so you can just call it directly with different types e.g. `Container.SomeNiceFunction(new List<int>(), new List<int>(), Eval1, Eval2);`

Comment: that will not compile in Visual Studio 2013

Comment: @DecafSux - It compiles for me, what error are you getting?

Comment: I need to do a re-edit above to show because code formatting sux here in comment sections.

Comment: @DecafSux - RE your edit, you're missing the `<T>` generic parameter list between the method name and paramter list: `SomeNiceFunction<T>(List<T> l1, List<T> l2...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Delegates declarations have no body. You can declare the function separately as shown below:

```
public class Program
{
    private static List<T> SomeNiceFunction<T>(List<T> l1, List<T> l2, MyEval1<T> e1, MyEval2<T> e2)
    {
        var result = new List<T>();
        foreach (var elem in l1)
        {
            var match = l2.FirstOrDefault(o => e1(o) && e2(o, elem));
            if (match != null)
                result.Add(match);
        }

        //... (some more code goes here)
        return result;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyDelegate<string> d = SomeNiceFunction;
    }

    private delegate bool MyEval1<T>(T a);

    private delegate bool MyEval2<T>(T a, T b);

    private delegate List<T> MyDelegate<T>(List<T> l1, List<T> l2, MyEval1<T> e1, MyEval2<T> e2);
}
```